# Unity design flaw : how to distinguish microphones with empty names or same names

Tags: windows, audio, unity-game-engine, audio-recording

What do you do it Microphone.devices returns a list of 6 devices and all of them are empty strings?

If I connect an external soundcard, it returns names in that list. Some of them are empty (from the pc) and some are from the card, with names.

So the problem is:

Microphone.start(X)   X needs to be a device name (design flaw. Very serious one). What happens if   Microphone.devices[x] = "" ? . Fmod takes the last one in the list, obviously. But what If I need to select a particular one in that empty list?

All devices are detected, and I can record audio using an empty string, because it chooses the last one in that list with that name. So it's working. But I have NO NAMES and no way to distinguish those ones.

Any other way to use a mic with no name? Device unique ID?  Any workaround?

The code I use to get the list of devices is using the Microphone class on the API. The ubiqutous:

```
foreach (string device in Microphone.devices) {
     Debug.Log("Name: " + device);
}
```

For which I get:

```
Log: Name: 
Log: Name:
...
Log: Name: Some name from the external card
Log: Name: Some name from the external card
```

Comment: Could you show the relevant code where you obtain the list of microphones?

Comment: @Hristo Added! It's so common and easy. Nothing related to code, but probably to drivers or something like that. I just want to avoid using this and use a better identification system, like a unique ID. Btw, I tried removing Realtek drivers. I saw this in one answer.

Comment: same problem here